# Prompt to CC before sending

Tags: microsoft-outlook, prompt

First post. I would like to make a function in excel that everytime I press send prompts me to cc an email address from a specified list. For example.

In VBA i have specified recipients (i.e. Mary@gmail.com and Jane@hotmail.com)

When I write an email and press send, I would like outlook to prompt me asking if I would like to add mary OR Jane OR neither in the cc field. Depending on my selection, the email address should be cc'ed and then sent.

It would be awesome if the prompt presents only a number of buttons corresponding to the number of email addresses in the list, so that the prompt only requires one click.

I have some experience with VBA using Excel, but none in outlook. I'm using Outlook 2010.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you click a button in Excel to send the e-mails? If so, sounds like you need an inputbox() with a message "Do you want to CC any other people?". then take the value from the input box, which can be a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses.